# Сортировка массива файлов (и директорий) для последующего показа в ListView

Tags: java, android, массивы, listview, adapter

Я создаю текстовый редактор для Андроид. При выборе опции "Сохранить как..." в нем открывается диалог для ввода имени файла и выбора папки для сохранения. Выбор папки сделан через ListView с наследником ArrayAdapter'a.

Список файлов и папок должен быть отсорирован следующим образом: сначала папки, потом файлы, причём и те и те должны быть, в свою очередь, рассортированы по алфавиту (по названиям). Сейчас это сделано так (код адаптера):

```
public class FileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<File>
{
    private final File[] files;
    private final Activity context;

    public FileAdapter (Activity context, File directory) {
        super (context, R.layout.list_item, directory.listFiles());
        this.context = context;

        File[] onlyDirs = directory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File f)
                {
                    if (f.isDirectory()) return true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        Arrays.sort(onlyDirs);
        File[] onlyFiles = directory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File f)
                {
                    if (f.isFile()) return true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        Arrays.sort(onlyFiles);

        File[] files = new File[onlyDirs.length + onlyFiles.length];
        System.arraycopy(onlyDirs, 0, files, 0, onlyDirs.length);
        System.arraycopy(onlyFiles, 0, files, onlyDirs.length, onlyFiles.length);


        this.files = files;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder vh;
        if (view==null){
            view =context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_text);
            vh.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_icon);
            view.setTag(vh);
        } else vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        vh.textView.setText(files[position].getName());

        if (files[position].isDirectory()) 
        vh.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder);
        else vh.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Во-первых, при открытии коревой директории при прокрутке до определенного файла (не знаю, какого) программа вылетает с ошибкой (а без сортировки массивов такого не было). Во-вторых, я уверен, что моя реализация обладает плохой производительностью и все можно сделать гораздо проще.
Прошу помочь упростить сортировку массива файлов и найти ошибку, из-за которой может вылетать. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Отправьте логи ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот мое решение на Java 8.

```
class FileAdapter {
private final File[] files;

public FileAdapter ( File directory) {

    File[] unorderedFiles = directory.listFiles();
    Comparator<File> comparator = (f1,f2) ->{
        if (f1.isDirectory() && f2.isFile())
            return 1;
        else if(f2.isDirectory() && f1.isFile())
            return -1;
        else 
            return f1.compareTo(f2);
    };
    TreeSet<File> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    treeSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(unorderedFiles));

    System.out.println(treeSet);
    this.files = (File[]) treeSet.toArray();}}
```

Если в дальнейшем планируется добавлять/удалять элементы из files, лучше его не преобразовывать к массиву а оставить как TreeSet. Первый параметр конструктора не должен повлиять на результат сортировки.

Замечу также, что данное решение не предполагает рекурсивный просмотр содержимого вложенных в directory папок.

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло, правда, мне пришлось переделать код под Java 7.